# Searching table and column based on the content

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search the content of MySQL table using information_schema or other method available.

I want to search for columns and tables which has id = 6783. There are 5 different tables which has same column name "id".

How would I achieve it?

Comment: information_schema does not know the data inside a table. Just query every table...

Comment: What if I have 500 tables, how efficient is searching every table?

Comment: i don't think there is an efficient way to search those tables. You can write a procedure or outside script to get the list of those table names and search each of them using a loop. The best you can do is jump out the loop as soon as you find a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to search for columns and tables which has id = 6783, using information_schema

1. Find the tables which has column named ”id”
2. & id value should be 6783

**Hints for point 1:**

If you connect to the “INFORMATION_SCHEMA” & execute “Show tables” command it will display all the tables which are present in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
Show tables;
```

In this table list you will find one table **“COLUMNS”**.
This table contains TABLE_NAME,TABLE_SCHEMA & COLUMN_NAME fields along with other fields.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA FROM COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME='id';
```

This above command will produce list of tables which has one column called “id” along with their schema details.

**Hints for point 2:**
Now you have TABLE_NAME and also the TABLE_SCHEMA. I would be happy if you really give a try and in case you stuck somewhere, let us know where you are struggling.Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create store procedure and whose first query would be to find table with id like pointed out by Arin. Then loop through those table and query for that id.